# Cannot create database migration on EF Core but It can when you ask to EnsureCreate database

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to inject some repository  to a service and some services to a controller but I am using the DbContext is an assembly that is not the startup project but oddily when i try to call to create a migration it tells me this design is not allowed but if I call the EnsureCreated() method it allows me to create the database... what could be happening

the error
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Repository.AppDbContext.AppDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Repository.AppDbContext.AppDbContext'. at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl

here is the Service DI

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ManagementServiceDb"));
            });
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => { 
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<Producto>, ProductoRepositorio>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<RegistroActividad>, RegistroActividadRepositorio>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<ProductoRegistroActividad>, RegistroActividadesProductoRepositorio>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<TipoActividad>, TipoActividadRepositorio>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<ApplicationUser>, UsuarioRepositorio>();

            services.AddScoped<UnidadRepositorio>();

            services.AddScoped<ProductosServicios>();
            services.AddScoped<UsuarioServicio>();

            services.AddScoped<UnidadServicios>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a parameterless constructor in your DbContext class.

If that doesn't work you might need to add a design time factory as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory).

Comment: since the AppDbContext is outside the webapi it seems to require a default contructor and also override onconfiguring that seems to be the issue it cant initialize the service because probably assumes the startup project is the startup project but it doesn't have any string connection configuration.. maybe that is the reason, thank you

Comment: @JulioFuentes, you can always [edit] your answer to fix things like that. I've done it for you this time.